# Replace keyword in anywhere in URL and 301 Redirect to new location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, find-replace

We've got lots of urls following a structure similar to (terrible i know)

```
.com/sale/product-x
.com/product-category/product-x
.com/product-x
.com/product-category/sub-category/product-x
```

There is in fact several hundred thousand of these...

We're hoping to use mod_rewrite to be able to replace "product-x" with "productx"

As you can see the "product-x" could be anywhere in the url - what we basically want is a "find-replace" like function for only the keyword "product-x"

--

How can we go about using the .htaccess file to create this desired effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)?product-x(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1productx%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Why not just do `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?product-x(/.*)?$ $1productx$2 [L,R=301,NE]` ?

Comment: Yes, I can use that as well but this one will work from any sub-directory's .htaccess as well. Do note that `$1productx$2` won't work without a `RewriteBase` defined above.

Comment: @Croises: No because `REQUEST_URI` represents value from leading slash after host name.

Comment: @anubhava I understand that. But that we replace any word, as long as we place it in the same relative place, the root does not matter. But forget that. It's not important ;-) Thank you !

Comment: Yes not important but I suspect I couldn't fully explain to you intent behind `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` here. Main difference is between relative path available for `RewriteRule` in `$1` and full path available in this solution for `%1`