# Remove string from any URL in a 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of old urls that all contain "qr_" in them. I would like to create a rule in the .htaccess file that would remove that string from all URLs which contain it.

Examples of desired output:

```
mydomain.com/qr_red --> mydomain.com/red
mydomain.com/qr_blue --> mydomain.com/blue
mydomain.com/qr_green --> mydomain.com/green
```

Would this code work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)?qr_(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

I've based it off of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058548/replace-keyword-in-anywhere-in-url-and-301-redirect-to-new-location), but I'm hesitant to deploy it because instead of replacing one string with another, I'm replacing it with nothing (`%1%2`)? Not sure if that'll break something, or if there's a cleaner way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^qr_(.*) /$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

Comment: @Tara: Did this work out?